# Wrapping about of a tikzpicture placed between two theorem-environments

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, wrap, ntheorem

How to place tikzpicture inside theorem environments with wrapping? I found many decisions with `cutwin` package. But the decisions concern to the wrapping inside own theorem environment (besides, they look cumbersome). But what if one need to place picture between two theorem-environments with wrapping?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\theoremseparator{-----------}
\newtheorem{theorem}{}
\input{insbox.tex}
\begin{document}


%=========================================================
\begin{theorem}
    \lipsum[1]
    %--------------- cutwin? wrapfig? anything else ? ------------------
    \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.5\linewidth}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    %---------------------------------------------------------  
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Desired view looks like the following
[image]

Comment: problem's the `wrapfigure` cannot be placed in list environments. you could thread the path with `picins`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `insbox`, which requires some manual adjustments:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newtheorem{theorem}{}
\input{insbox.tex}

\begin{document}
%=========================================================

\begin{theorem}\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\InsertBoxR{6}{\parbox{5.2cm}{\raggedleft\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \captionof{figure}{}\label{mylabel}}}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\InsertBoxR{0}{\quad\makebox[5cm]{}}[3]
    \lipsum[2]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case  these theorems are numbered bu=y section, you have to change the value of `\parindent` inside the theorem. This can be done with `\theoremprework`. Also, note the `change` theorem style gives a better positioning of the label:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

 \theoremstyle{change}
 \theoremprework{\parindent=2em}
 \newtheorem{theorem}{}[section]

\input{insbox.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\InsertBoxR{6}{\parbox{5.2cm}{\raggedleft\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \captionof{figure}{}\label{mylabel}}}\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\InsertBoxR{0}{\quad\makebox[5cm]{}}[3]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! As a temporary solution it will do. But, unfortunately, too much needs to be corrected by hands.

Comment: It should be more or less automatic if the tikz picture does not overflow to the next theorem? Other tha that, since your ‘theorem’ has no name, couldn't you consider using an `enumerate` environment indtead, as you  can have the tools from `enumitem`?

Comment: I do not consider the `enumitem`, for my purposes, the  `ntheorem` is required only.

Comment: Maybe there is some way to determine the size of the tikzpicture to put it in `\parbox {<size>} {...}` and to other required places?

Comment: I suppose so. Then you can convert this code into a macro, and the only parameters to enter would be 1) the width of the parbox, 2) How many lines are untouched at the beginning of the theorem (it's the first argument of `insbox`) and, as an optional argument, the number of supplementary shortened lines at the end (I used it to shorten the first lines of the second theorem).

Comment: @Bernarn I found an Unpleasant thing, if I add in preamble `\newtheorem{theorem}{}[section]`, the number of theorem overlaped by text of theorem.

Comment: Try adding, before declaring you theorem, `theoremseparator{\quad}`, or some length that fits your needs

Comment: Unfortunantly, the `\theoremseparator` does not helped.   With `\InsertBoxR`, theorem body text has the same identation. The `insbox.tex` breack some length. UPD MWE

Comment: @sergiokapone: I've added a solution. Please see my edit.