# Indentation in ntheorem with inserted picture

Tags: spacing, indentation, theorems, wrap, ntheorem

My question is additional to [Wrapping about of a tikzpicture placed between two theorem-environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436022/wraping-about-of-a-tikzpicture-placed-between-two-theorem-environments). As one can see from [CTAN:Text flow](https://ctan.org/topic/text-flow), the method of wrapping figure inside theorem-like (lists,...) environments is poorly designed.

The only one method (*I would like to believe that I am mistaken, correct in the answers*), that is allow to wrap picture placed in between two theorem environments are the macros from within `insbox.tex`, which are used the mechanism of `\parshape`.

But this method has has a drawback. The macros `\InsertBox(R\L\C) {...}` get the its arguments and form the content of theorem environment as a simple paragraph with the global `\parindent` length  and completely ignore the lengths, defined by theorem environment (labelwidth, labelsep, leftmargin, etc.).

The MWE illustrate the problem

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


\theoremstyle{change}
%\theoremprework{\parindent=2em}
\newtheorem{theorem}{}[section]

\input{insbox.tex}
\begin{document}

    \section{title 1}
        \begin{theorem}\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}

        \InsertBoxR{6}{\parbox{5.2cm}{\raggedleft\begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \captionof{figure}{}\label{mylabel1}}}[5]
        \lipsum[1]

    \end{theorem}
    \setcounter{section}{100} % ===== for showing problem ========
\begin{theorem}\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\InsertBoxR{0}{\quad\makebox[5.2cm]{}}[3]
    \parindent = 10ex % =====  This length should be adjusted automatically depending on lalelwidth + labelsep
    \lipsum[2]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that `\InsertBoxR` ends the paragraph. Thus the text is considered a new one, getting indented by only `\parindent`. This can be corrected by undoing `\parindent` and inserting `\labelsep` and the space for the label. Below, this is done with the new macro `\thindent`.

I also removed the `\quad` in the second `\InsertBoxR` since in the second theorem the lines where shorter then in the first.

The code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


\theoremstyle{change}
%\theoremprework{\parindent=2em}
\newtheorem{theorem}{}[section]

\newcommand{\thindent}{%
    \setbox0\hbox{\rmfamily\bfseries\thetheorem}% for getting the label width
    \hspace*{-\parindent}% undo parskip
    \hspace*{\wd0}%        width of label
    \hspace*{\labelsep}%
}

\input{insbox.tex}
\begin{document}
\section{title 1}
\begin{theorem}\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    \InsertBoxR{6}{\parbox{5.2cm}{\raggedleft
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{}\label{mylabel1}}}[5]%
    \thindent
    \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\setcounter{section}{100} % ===== for showing problem ========
\begin{theorem}\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\InsertBoxR{0}{\makebox[5.2cm]{}}[3]% removed \quad
    \thindent
    \lipsum[2]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]